# Problema para envio de Email com PHPMAILER usando uma conta GMAIL para envio

Tags: php, phpmailer

Código

```
require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Charset = 'utf-8';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'email@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'senha';
$mail->From = 'email@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Eu';
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Subject = 'Teste';
$mail->AddAddress('toemail@gmail.com', 'toemail');
$mail->MsgHTML("Segue em anexo o contrato");
$enviado = $mail->Send();
if ($enviado) {
    echo "ok";
} else {
    echo "erro";
}
```

Resultado

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. erro
```

Configuração na Conta:

```
Permitir aplicativos menos seguros: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps
Permitir acesso à sua Conta do Google: https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
Desativar verificação em duas etapas ou criar uma senha para o e-mail https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1064203?hl=pt-BR


* Testes:

ssl na porta 465 ou com tls na porta 587 (Falha nos 2),
mesmo com as configurações na conta de envio o erro persiste.
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo,

Configure o Postfix que é mais facil:

Configurando Postfix com Gmail:
Instalando pacotes essenciais:

```
sudo apt-get install postfix mailutils libsasl2-2 ca-certificates libsasl2-modules
```

*Caso você não possua o Postfix instalado, o assistente de instalação irá realizar algumas perguntas. Basta selecionar o servidor como Internet Site e para FQDN algo como mail.dominio.com.br

Abra o arquivo de configuração do Postfix:

```
vim /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

Insira as seguintes linhas no main.cf:

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_use_tls = yes
```

Agora vamos criar o arquivos que contém as informações de usuário e senha do Gmail:

```
vim /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

Adicione a seguinte linha no sasl_passwd:

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587 USERNAME:PASSWORD
```

*Não é necessário informar @gmail.com no usuário, se utilizar o Google App’s domain insira USERNAME@dominio.com.br.

Agora vamos setar as permissões:

```
sudo chmod 400 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

Realizamos um restart do Postfix:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postfix reload
```

Pronto! Agora vamos ao Teste.

Testando
Primeiramente e muito importante!

Para evitar o seguinte erro:
Error: “SASL authentication failed; server smtp.gmail.com”

Devemos desbloquear o captcha do google, acesse:
https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Agora vamos enviar um e-mail de teste:

```
echo "Assunto: Testando E-mail" | mail -s "Corpo: Teste." seu_email@gmail.com
```

Pronto! Você já deve receber o e-mail de teste na sua caixa de entrada!

Caso não receba o e-mail, é possível acompanhar os erros no seguinte arquivo de log:

```
tail -f /var/log/mail.log
```

Fonte: http://novustec.com.br/artigos/configurando_postfix_gmail_smtp

Comment: Vou testar, muito obrigado.